# Get a pixel array from from golang image.Image

Tags: go

I need to get a pixel array in the form of `[]byte` to be passed to the `texImage2D` method of a [Contex](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/mobile/gl#Context) from the [/mobile/gl](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/mobile/gl) package.

It needs a pixel array where rgba values of each pixel is appended in the order of pixels left to right, top to bottom. Currently I have an image loaded from a file.

```
a, err := asset.Open("key.jpeg")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer a.Close()

img, _, err := image.Decode(a)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

I am looking for something like `img.Pixels()`

Comment: This might be useful to you: https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/mobile/exp/gl/glutil#Image

Comment: The [image package documentation](https://tip.golang.org/pkg/image/#Image) makes this obvious.

Answer (score 15):

You can simply use `img.At(x, y).RGBA()` to get the RBGA values for a pixel, you just need to divide them by 257 to get the 8 bit representation. I'd recommend building your own bi-dimensional array of pixels. Here's a possible implementation, modify it as needed:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "image"
    "image/png"
    "os"
    "io"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    // You can register another format here
    image.RegisterFormat("png", "png", png.Decode, png.DecodeConfig)

    file, err := os.Open("./image.png")

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error: File could not be opened")
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    defer file.Close()

    pixels, err := getPixels(file)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error: Image could not be decoded")
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    fmt.Println(pixels)
}

// Get the bi-dimensional pixel array
func getPixels(file io.Reader) ([][]Pixel, error) {
    img, _, err := image.Decode(file)

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    bounds := img.Bounds()
    width, height := bounds.Max.X, bounds.Max.Y

    var pixels [][]Pixel
    for y := 0; y < height; y++ {
        var row []Pixel
        for x := 0; x < width; x++ {
            row = append(row, rgbaToPixel(img.At(x, y).RGBA()))
        }
        pixels = append(pixels, row)
    }

    return pixels, nil
}

// img.At(x, y).RGBA() returns four uint32 values; we want a Pixel
func rgbaToPixel(r uint32, g uint32, b uint32, a uint32) Pixel {
    return Pixel{int(r / 257), int(g / 257), int(b / 257), int(a / 257)}
}

// Pixel struct example
type Pixel struct {
    R int
    G int
    B int
    A int
}
```

Comment: Why 257? Why not 256?

Comment: The values are multiplied by 101 in base 16, which means 257 in base 10. I'm don't remember what's special about the number or why this is done, but the result should be an integer < 256, otherwise you have a different representation for pixels (depends on the img type).

Comment: @Kesarion If you look at [rgbaModel](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/dev.boringcrypto.go1.10/src/image/color/color.go#L176) (which implements `color.RGBAModel`) it just does `>> 8`. In general if you have a `color.Color` and you want a specific format you use a color model to do the conversion; in this case `color.RGBAModel`. If you want most or all of an image in the format and memory isn't a concern it's best to use `image/draw` to bulk convert (taking advantage of it's optimizations) then you can use `image.RGBA`'s `RGBAAt()` or `.Pix` slice.

Comment: The x and y are flipped in this example

Comment: For deciding whether to use ```.Pix()``` or ```.At()``` it really depends on how many pixels you need to work with in relation to how many total pixels exist in the given image. I've written up a detailed explanation of how ```.Pix()``` is better for when you need many pixels, and ```.At()``` makes more sense when you just need a few https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70616183/is-img-at-or-rgba-pix-faster-better-for-retrieving-pixel-data-from-a-golang/70616459#70616459

Answer (score 10):

This is what I ended up doing. I am using [image/draw](https://golang.org/pkg/image/draw/) package's Draw function to refill an `image.RGBA` instance

```
rect := img.Bounds()
rgba := image.NewRGBA(rect)
draw.Draw(rgba, rect, img, rect.Min, draw.Src)
```

Now `rgba.Pix` contains the array I want and can be used in the `TexImage2D` method.

```
glctx.TexImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, rect.Max.X-rect.Min.X, rect.Max.Y-rect.Min.Y, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, rgba.Pix)
```

**Alternately**

[Image](https://golang.org/pkg/image/#Image) instances contains an `At` method that returns a [Color](https://golang.org/pkg/image/color/#Color). So it is possible to loop through each pixel and and collect colors. But converting returned rgba values from the `Color` might be complex. Quoting documentation:

```
    // RGBA returns the alpha-premultiplied red, green, blue and alpha values
    // for the color. Each value ranges within [0, 0xffff], but is represented
    // by a uint32 so that multiplying by a blend factor up to 0xffff will not
    // overflow.
    //
    // An alpha-premultiplied color component c has been scaled by alpha (a),
    // so has valid values 0 <= c <= a.
```

Comment: I would check if the image is already an RGBA first, and just use Pix directly in that case. Also, using `At` isn't complex, it's just inefficient, which is why we have access to Pix.

Comment: Actually, using the At function isn't so hard... `r,g,b,a := image.At(x,y).RGBA() ` and then `red := uint8(r>>8)` etc.

Answer (score 4):

In my test, `Pix` method shows **~4 times faster** than `At`, but still takes too long...

Here is my test script, not sure about the `height` / `width` order, but this works for me:

```golang
// test_image_time.go
package main

import (
    "os"
    "fmt"
    "image"
    _ "image/jpeg"
    "golang.org/x/image/draw"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    img_path:= "/path/to/image/.jpg"
    aa := time.Now()
    reader, _ := os.Open(img_path)
    m, _, _ := image.Decode(reader)
    bounds := m.Bounds()
    fmt.Println("Bounds: ", bounds.Min.Y, bounds.Max.Y, bounds.Min.X, bounds.Max.X)
    bb := time.Now()
    fmt.Println("Read file time: ", float64(bb.Nanosecond() - aa.Nanosecond()) / 1e9)

    aa = time.Now()
    _ = image_2_array_at(m)
    bb = time.Now()
    fmt.Println("At Time: ", float64(bb.Nanosecond() - aa.Nanosecond()) / 1e9)

    aa = time.Now()
    _ = image_2_array_pix(m)
    bb = time.Now()
    fmt.Println("Pix Time: ", float64(bb.Nanosecond() - aa.Nanosecond()) / 1e9)
}

func image_2_array_at(src image.Image) [][][3]float32 {
    bounds := src.Bounds()
    width, height := bounds.Max.X, bounds.Max.Y
    iaa := make([][][3]float32, height)

    for y := 0; y < height; y++ {
        row := make([][3]float32, width)
        for x := 0; x < width; x++ {
            r, g, b, _ := src.At(x, y).RGBA()
            // A color's RGBA method returns values in the range [0, 65535].
            // Shifting by 8 reduces this to the range [0, 255].
            row[x] = [3]float32{float32(r>>8), float32(g>>8), float32(b>>8)}
        }
        iaa[y] = row
    }

    return iaa
}

func image_2_array_pix(src image.Image) [][][3]float32 {
    bounds := src.Bounds()
    width, height := bounds.Max.X, bounds.Max.Y
    iaa := make([][][3]float32, height)
    src_rgba := image.NewRGBA(src.Bounds())
    draw.Copy(src_rgba, image.Point{}, src, src.Bounds(), draw.Src, nil)

    for y := 0; y < height; y++ {
        row := make([][3]float32, width)
        for x := 0; x < width; x++ {
            idx_s := (y * width + x) * 4
            pix := src_rgba.Pix[idx_s : idx_s + 4]
            row[x] = [3]float32{float32(pix[0]), float32(pix[1]), float32(pix[2])}
        }
        iaa[y] = row
    }

    return iaa
}
```

**Run**

```sh
$ go run test_image_time.go
Bounds:  0 976 0 1920
Read file time:  0.025212067
At Time:  0.069091218
Pix Time:  0.0165787
```

Comment: I've written up a more detail comparison inspired by your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70616183/is-img-at-or-rgba-pix-faster-better-for-retrieving-pixel-data-from-a-golang/70616459#70616459
Hopefully this helps people decide.