# Go image bytes and Python PIL tobytes produce different byte data

Tags: python, image, go, python-imaging-library, byte

I have taken over some code that was previously in python written by someone else, and no is in go, written by myself.

Part of this code was to open an image, read its data, and make an MD5 hash to prevent duplicates.

The python version of this code used PIL:

```
from PIL import Image
f = Image.open('2d16395b-da48-11eb-8cbe-36a331f79a1e.png')
hashlib.md5(f.tobytes()).hexdigest()
'c699a448b38df386d036ed418d7714f3'
```

And the go version just read the bytes into an md5 hash

```
    f, _ := os.Open(p)
    _, err := f.Seek(0, io.SeekStart)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    h := md5.New()
    if _, err := io.Copy(h, f); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    hb := h.Sum(nil)
    hash := hex.EncodeToString(hb)
```

However these produce different MD5.

It seems like the PIL library is readying the bytes differently, maybe stripping of header/metadata or something?

Does anyone know of a way i can replicate the byte-read of PIL in go to get the same MD5 hash?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to start with the (dummy) test image that I used:

[image]

which is a *32X16* (*RGBA*) *.png* with only 2 colors:

- Red (237, 28, 36)
- Blue (0, 0, 255)

Back to the question: [[ReadTheDocs.Pillow]: Image.load()](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.load) (called implicitly by *open*) processes (decodes) the image, yielding its raw bitmap data, which is totally different than the (encoded) file contents.

Here's the difference between the 2.

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
from PIL import Image
from hashlib import md5


def read_file_data(file_name):
    with open(file_name, "rb") as fin:
        return fin.read()


def read_img_data(file_name):
    with Image.open(file_name) as img:
        return img.tobytes()


def process_bytes(buf, first=20, last=20):
    print("Len: {:d}\nFirst bytes:\n  ".format(len(buf)), end=" ")
    for i in range(first):
        print("0x{:02X}".format(buf[i]), end=" ")
    print("\nLast bytes:\n  ", end=" ")
    for i in range(-last, 0, 1):
        print("0x{:02X}".format(buf[i]), end=" ")
    print("\nMD5: {:}".format(md5(buf).hexdigest()))


def main(*argv):
    img_name = "rb.png"
    funcs = [
        read_file_data,
        read_img_data,
    ]
    for func in funcs:
        print("\nFunction {:s}".format(func.__name__))
        b = func(img_name)
        process_bytes(b)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q068231412]> sopr.bat
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.08.07_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py
> Python 3.8.7 (tags/v3.8.7:6503f05, Dec 21 2020, 17:59:51) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
>
> Function read_file_data:
> Len: 169
> First bytes:
>    0x89 0x50 0x4E 0x47 0x0D 0x0A 0x1A 0x0A 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x0D 0x49 0x48 0x44 0x52 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x10
> Last bytes:
>    0xE2 0x8A 0x24 0x69 0x53 0x4C 0xB3 0x03 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x49 0x45 0x4E 0x44 0xAE 0x42 0x60 0x82
> MD5: 8368b5c29a12b298cea2ad4b32955830
>
> Function read_img_data:
> Len: 2048
> First bytes:
>    0xED 0x1C 0x24 0xFF 0xED 0x1C 0x24 0xFF 0xED 0x1C 0x24 0xFF 0xED 0x1C 0x24 0xFF 0xED 0x1C 0x24 0xFF
> Last bytes:
>    0x00 0x00 0xFF 0xFF 0x00 0x00 0xFF 0xFF 0x00 0x00 0xFF 0xFF 0x00 0x00 0xFF 0xFF 0x00 0x00 0xFF 0xFF
> MD5: ebdf44b7ad36d79b221a70ea2b0fa0c7
>
> Done.
> ```

After some hours of research (trial and error, *Google*ing, reading *doc*s and examples - I can't afford not mention here [[SO]: Get a pixel array from from golang image.Image (@ArunaHerath's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33198436/4788546)), I was able to translate the above script to *Go*.

*code00.go*:

```golang
package main

import (
    "crypto/md5"
    "fmt"
    "image"
    "image/draw"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"

    _ "image/gif"
    _ "image/jpeg"
    _ "image/png"
)

type ImageFunc func(string) []byte
type ImageFuncs []ImageFunc

func ReadFileData(fileName string) []byte {
    buf, _ := ioutil.ReadFile(fileName)
    return buf
}

func ReadImgData(fileName string) []byte {
    reader, _ := os.Open(fileName)
    defer reader.Close()
    img, _, _ := image.Decode(reader)
    rect := img.Bounds()
    rgba := image.NewRGBA(rect)
    draw.Draw(rgba, rect, img, rect.Min, draw.Src)
    //fmt.Printf("%v\n", rgba.Pix)
    return rgba.Pix
}

func ProcessBytes(buf []byte, first int, last int) {
    lb := len(buf)
    fmt.Printf("Len: %d\nFirst bytes:\n  ", lb)
    for i := 0; i < first; i++ {
        fmt.Printf("0x%02X ", buf[i])
    }
    fmt.Printf("\nLast bytes:\n  ")
    for i := lb - last; i < lb; i++ {
        fmt.Printf("0x%02X ", buf[i])
    }
    fmt.Printf("\nMD5: %x", md5.Sum(buf))
}

func main() {
    imgName := "rb.png"
    first := 20
    last := 20
    funcs := ImageFuncs{
        ReadFileData,
        ReadImgData,
    }
    for idx := range funcs {
        function := funcs[idx]
        fmt.Printf("\n\nFunction %#v:\n", function)
        b := function(imgName)
        ProcessBytes(b, first, last)
    }
    fmt.Printf("\n\nDone.\n")
}
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [prompt]> "f:\Install\pc064\Google\GoLang\1.16.5\bin\go.exe" run code00.go
>
>
> Function (main.ImageFunc)(0x9f1060):
> Len: 169
> First bytes:
>   0x89 0x50 0x4E 0x47 0x0D 0x0A 0x1A 0x0A 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x0D 0x49 0x48 0x44 0x52 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x10
> Last bytes:
>   0xE2 0x8A 0x24 0x69 0x53 0x4C 0xB3 0x03 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x49 0x45 0x4E 0x44 0xAE 0x42 0x60 0x82
> MD5: 8368b5c29a12b298cea2ad4b32955830
>
> Function (main.ImageFunc)(0x9f10e0):
> Len: 2048
> First bytes:
>   0xED 0x1C 0x24 0xFF 0xED 0x1C 0x24 0xFF 0xED 0x1C 0x24 0xFF 0xED 0x1C 0x24 0xFF 0xED 0x1C 0x24 0xFF
> Last bytes:
>   0x00 0x00 0xFF 0xFF 0x00 0x00 0xFF 0xFF 0x00 0x00 0xFF 0xFF 0x00 0x00 0xFF 0xFF 0x00 0x00 0xFF 0xFF
> MD5: ebdf44b7ad36d79b221a70ea2b0fa0c7
>
> Done.
> ```

**Notes**:

- **Important**: I've only tested the code with the (dummy) *RGBA* image, for other color formats it might need additional work
- As seen, I didn't do any error handling, in order to keep code short (but anyway, that's beyond this question's scope)

Comment: No, this is what I'm doing - and it's not the same result. You can even see if you read it with pil readbytes, and print the first 50 bytes versus the first 50 read by a usual rb file read it's not the same as you show. And reading it in go I cannot replicate what tobytes is doing. Using image decode isn't helpful in this case sadly

Comment: I think this answer is helpful. It's showing that the `tobytes()` method is returning a view of the decoded bytes of the image -- not the raw bytes of the file. @aescript To replicate what PIL is doing in go, you need to decode the image, and take the MD5 of the bytes representing the RGB(A) values of the image as bytes.

Comment: How so though. I tried it hashing them concatenated like R+B+G and I tried R1+B1+G1+R2+B2+G2... Etc and nothing replicatea what I get from pil. That's why I'm asking this

Comment: @aescript: I don't think I understand. I shown what the results are using *PIL*, and simply reading the image (that you do from *Go*), and they differ (the fact their sizes differ is enough, calculating the hash is useless). So you also have to decode the image too in *Go*. singe I am not familiar with *Go* (probably there should be an image encoding/decoding library) I indicated the other *URL* (which seems to do so).

Comment: I know what the results are in PIL. What I'm saying is that I cannot replicate that in go, and nothing you provided does so.

Comment: That's true. I 1st came into contact with *Go* when looking to this question. Anyway I was trying to point that what you 're attempting is completely wrong. Still working on it...

Comment: @aescript: Did you have a chance to look at the (*Go*) code that I provided?

Answer (score 1):

There's a fundamental misunderstanding here.

A JPEG/PNG/TIFF file is **encoded** on disk. It contains some, or all, of the following:

- image width and height
- image colourspace and compression tables
- date of creation
- GPS coordinates
- author
- copyright
- compressed pixels

The first few bytes will be a JPEG/PNG magic number (or signature) followed by other PNG chunks, or JPEG sections, containing the info itemised above.

A `PIL Image`, after conversion to bytes, contains only uncompressed pixels. The first few bytes will be the top-left pixel, the next few bytes will be the second pixel across in the first row.

They are **fundamentally** different and will never have the same MD5 checksum.

Comment: I understand that. The point of this question is asking if there is a library or something for golang that will give me the raw pixel bytes just like pil does... There isn't really a misunderstanding, just looking for a similar function I can use in another language