# How to get rgb color from pixel in go

Tags: go, png, rgb

Golang newbie here, I'm trying to create a script that takes a png, gets the rgb values of each pixel, formats it into css colors and pushes them into a slice so that I can then have it create the png image in html & css (stupid project I know)

I'm able to do most things but for some reason, the colors aren't correct. I have as input a 2px image.

The colors are as follows (left to right): `[black, white, black, white]`

So I would expect to get this `[0 0 0 255 | 255 255 255 255 | 0 0 0 255 | 255 255 255 255]`

I'm getting these values instead: `[254 0 0 0| 254 254 255 2 | 2 2 255 1 | 1 1 255 254]`

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "image"
    "image/draw"
    "image/png"
    "log"
    "math"
    "os"
)

func imageLoader(path string) *os.File {
    image.RegisterFormat("png", "png", png.Decode, png.DecodeConfig)

    file, err := os.Open(path)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error: File could not be opened")
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    return file
}

func main() {
    pngImage := imageLoader("./2pxImg.png")

    img, err := png.Decode(pngImage)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    rect := img.Bounds()
    rgbaArr := image.NewRGBA(rect)
    draw.Draw(rgbaArr, rect, img, rect.Min, draw.Src)

    var rgba [4]uint8
    var hexArr = make([]string, 0, len(rgbaArr.Pix)/4)

    rgbaIdx := 0
    for idx, colorVal := range rgbaArr.Pix {
        rgba[rgbaIdx] = colorVal
        rgbaIdx += 1
        // modulus 4 because rgba has 4 values
        if idx%4 == 0 {
            rgbaIdx = 0
            hexArr = append(hexArr, rgbaToCssColor(&rgba, true))
        }

    }
}

func rgbaToCssColor(rgba *[4]uint8, isRgb bool) string {
    fmt.Printf("%v, %v, %v, %v\n", rgba[0], rgba[1], rgba[2], rgba[3])
    if isRgb {
        alpha := math.Floor((float64(rgba[3])/255)*10) / 10
        return fmt.Sprintf("rgba(%v, %v, %v, %v)", rgba[0], rgba[1], rgba[2], alpha)
    }
    return fmt.Sprintf("#%02x%02x%02x%02x", rgba[0], rgba[1], rgba[2], rgba[3])

}
```

I have used this stackoverflow answer to get the rgba values
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33198436/9118002