# Is img.At() or rgba.Pix() faster/better for retrieving pixel data from a Golang image.Image?

Tags: go

Reading the answers from [Get a pixel array from from golang image.Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33186783/get-a-pixel-array-from-from-golang-image-image), I saw that there were two methods of pixel RGBA retrieval, via `img.At()` and `rgba.Pix()`.

Which is better to use? Should one always be used, or are there cases where one should be used over the other and vice versa?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your program will be conducting a computation where you need a majority, if not all of the pixel data, then `rgba.Pix()` significantly outperforms `img.At()`. If you only need the pixel data of a single or few pixels in an image, use `img.At()` (the overhead of computing the `rgba.Pix()` prerequisite is too high in such cases).

Here are the results of various test loads, the durations of which are averaged over 10 samples each.

| Method | 1x1 | 1000x667 | 3840x2160 | 1000x667 + computation | 1000x667 only 5x5 accessed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `img.At()` | 195ns | 30.211071ms | 294.885396ms | 853.345043ms | 42.431**μs** |
| `rgba.Pix()` | 719ns | 7.786029ms | 77.700552ms | 836.480063ms | 6.791461**ms** |

We can see how for the tiny 1x1 image and the image where we limit our for loops to upper bounds of 5, using `img.At()` results in faster execution time. However, for use cases where every pixel is fetched, `rgba.Pix()` results in better performance. This improvement in performance is less evident the more computation we do with every pixel, as the total time increases and the difference between `img.At()` and `rgba.Pix()` becomes less obvious, as seen in "*1000x667 + computation*" in the table above.

Here is the test code used:

```
func main() {
    resp, err := http.Get("IMAGE URL GOES HERE")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    img, _, err := image.Decode(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    var start time.Time
    var duration time.Duration
    samples := 10
    var sum time.Duration

    fmt.Println("Samples: ", samples)
    sum = time.Duration(0)
    for i := 0; i < samples; i++ {
        start = time.Now()
        usingAt(img)
        duration = time.Since(start)
        sum += duration
    }
    fmt.Println("*** At avg: ", sum/time.Duration(samples))

    sum = time.Duration(0)
    for i := 0; i < samples; i++ {
        start = time.Now()
        usingPix(img)
        duration = time.Since(start)
        sum += duration
    }
    fmt.Println("*** Pix avg: ", sum/time.Duration(samples))
}

func usingAt(img image.Image) {
    bounds := img.Bounds()
    width, height := bounds.Max.X, bounds.Max.Y

    for y := 0; y < height; y++ {
        for x := 0; x < width; x++ {
            r, g, b, _ := img.At(x, y).RGBA()
            _ = uint8(r >> 8)
            _ = uint8(g >> 8)
            _ = uint8(b >> 8)
        }
    }
}

func usingPix(img image.Image, targetColor colorful.Color) {
    bounds := img.Bounds()
    width, height := bounds.Max.X, bounds.Max.Y

    rgba := image.NewRGBA(bounds)
    draw.Draw(rgba, bounds, img, bounds.Min, draw.Src)
    for y := 0; y < height; y++ {
        for x := 0; x < width; x++ {
            index := (y*width + x) * 4
            pix := rgba.Pix[index : index+4]
            _ = pix[0]
            _ = pix[1]
            _ = pix[2]
        }
    }
}
```

*1000x667 only 5x5 accessed* replaced the `height` and `width` in the for loops with 5 and 5, limiting the number of pixels accessed.

*1000x667 + computation* actually used the RGB values by comparing each pixel's color distance from a target color with [go-colorful](https://github.com/lucasb-eyer/go-colorful)'s DE2000 calculation.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I confirmed that for processing multiple pixels at once in a loop it is 5x faster for my workload using the raw slice Pix data. Tip: try a type assertion of `img.(*image.RGBA)` and only if that fails do the image.NewRGBA() shown above.